# How to add native project and use native function in other c++ project

Tags: android, c++

I am working on android project.I have created a native edittext.I want use native jni function 
in other android c++ project for display the edittext in c++.whenever i add the headerfile of
jni and edittext,then compiler does not find.

Can you suggest me.how to add native edittext project with my own project and how to use jni function with c++.
Your suggestion will helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Take your code you want to share and place it into it's own compiled library. Then you can reference it in both the android project and the c++ project and use the code in both.

[How to create and use static librarys in c++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627.aspx)

[How to add libraries in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749733/how-to-add-libraries-in-c)