# Add C++ library (.a) to Android Project

Tags: android, c++

I have developed a library .a in C++ in xcode. I would like to know how to add it to my android project in Eclipse. I have tried different kind of ways found on the internet, but without success.
My library.a is added to the project.

I´ve seen [How to add libraries in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749733/how-to-add-libraries-in-c), but I can´t solve it.

Comment: What exactly have you tried and why did it fail?

Comment: Sooner or later you're going to have to dive into the [Android NDK](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html) to do this.

Comment: I have followed this tutorial:
http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-development/

It gives the following errors in simulation:Archive for required library: 'libs/liblibreriaParti.a' in project '*' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file
Program "E:\Escritorio\android-ndk-r9d" not found in PATH
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved

Comment: Can you please show the code for loading library?